# How can i Create or Generate New Entity on RunTIme In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, dynamic, iphonecoredatarecipes

I am working on a core Data based project. I want to create dynamic core data  entities on runtime with name of current date.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create *entities* dynamically but you can create *managed objects* dynamically, in your object graph.

Probably you should read a little of the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html).  At least read up to and including the section [Creating and Saving Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH5-SW1), which explains the answer to your first question in great detail.

Regarding the *name of the current date*, if you mean a string expressing the current date, you should first add such an attribute to your entity.  It is more conventional and usually better for localization to make this attribute of type *date* and transform to/from a string for the user interface.  You get the current date with [`Date.init()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) object, and convert it to a string using a [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).